# Correlation coefficient for three variables in r

Tags: r, correlation, equation

For three n-dimensional non-zero-variance variables a, b, and c, n > 2, if
r(ab), r(bc), and r(ac) are Pearson’s correlation coefficients between a and b, between b and c, and between a and c, respectively, then correlation coefficient r(abc) among a, b, and c is defined as:

r^2(abc) = ( r^2(ab) + r^2(bc) + r^2(ac) ) - ( 2 x r(ab) x r(bc) x r(ac) )

I was able to get the code for a manual way of doing it:

```
a <- c(4, 6, 2, 7)
b <- c(8, 1, 3, 5)
c <- c(6, 3, 1, 9)

al <- data.frame(a, b, c)
al


ab_cor <- cor(al$a, al$b, method = c("pearson"))
bc_cor <- cor(al$b, al$c, method = c("pearson"))
ac_cor <- cor(al$a, al$c, method = c("pearson"))

abc_cor <- sqrt( ( (ab_cor)^2 + (bc_cor)^2 + (ac_cor)^2 ) - ( 2 * ab_cor * bc_cor * ac_cor) )
abc_cor
```

But I was wondering if this could be done with less lines of code, for example with a for loop. Addittionaly, how would I write it so that I could do it with more than 3 variables as well, for example, r(abcd) i.e. r(ab), r(ac), r(ad), r(bc), r(bd), and r(cd).

Comment: To me it's not clear what you would want the calculation to look like for more than 3 variables. If you provide an example of the more generalized version (or even just for 4 variables) then that would be helpful.

Comment: The equation would look like this: r^2(abcd) = ( r^2(ab) + r^2(ac)  + r^2(ad) + r^2(bc) + r^2(bd)+ r^2(cd) ) - ( 2 x r(ab) x r(ac) x r(ad) x r(bc) x r(bd) x r(cd) )

Comment: Did you mean for there to be more in there?

Comment: But doing this manually would be tedious, especially when we start adding more and more variables. The equation would get exponentially longer, but if there is a way I can do it via a for loop, it should be able to reiterate through all the correlation combination and just dump out the values into a list.

Comment: The formula is basically the summation of the square of all the correlation combinations subtracted by 2 times the multiples of all the correlation combinations. I can add an image link if its harder to see when written out in text

Answer (score 2):

The cor function already creates a matrix of the correlations.  You just need to pick out the relevant ones and then use some vector operations.

```
cs <- cor(al, method = "pearson")

cs <- cs[upper.tri(cs)]

#sqrt(sum(cs^2)) - 2*prod(cs)
# apparently it's
sqrt(sum(cs^2) - 2*prod(cs))
```

This generalizes to your larger case as well assuming that you have all the variables you want in your `al` data.frame.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks for catching that